# How can I call the function of Report in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this scenario: Report names are in a table. I get them as string, e.g. `rpt!Report="Reportabc"`.

Now I want to call the function of this report. I know there is function `doWork()`, but how can I call this function of this report?

I tried `[Report]"& rpt!Report &".doWork` but it gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
Call Reports(rpt!Report).doWork()
```

`doWork()` must be a **public** function (or sub).

Comment: I tried doing this it gives me an error The report name 'Reportabc' you entered is misspelled or refers to a report that isn't open or doesn't exist.

Comment: @MuhammadHisham: Yes, the report must be open. Why would you want to call a function in a closed report? This function should be placed in a standard module. -- You can do `Call Report_Reportabc.doWork()` on a closed report, but there is no way to use a variable name in this syntax.